# Cache issue on drupal 8 endpoint

Tags: php, caching, drupal

I am developing a small application, I have to list the nodes of type article in an endpoint that I have in a module:

[image]

When I add an article, I am forced to clear the drupal cache, but the client does not want to have to do this, since the creation of the articles will be automated, I know that there are ways to handle the contexts, tags, cache keys, but I have never managed to understand exactly how this works and I think this would be a good example to understand it.

Comment: code should be always added as text

Comment: Can you use Views to build and return this data?  It will handle the caching for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on [Cache API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api) to understand how the cache system works in Drupal.

In above case, you will want to use **Cache tags** because they describes dependencies on data. In particular, you need to add `node_list` - list cache tag for `Node` entities (invalidated whenever any `Node` entity is updated, deleted or created):

```php
return [
  '#theme' => 'test_cache',
  '#items' => $items,
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => ['node_list'],
  ],
];
```

You can see the common cache tags [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-tags).